# EACCES while installing hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm having difficulty installing the hyperledger composer locally on a Ubuntu system as per https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html.  I think I've met all of the requirements:

```
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ node --version
v6.10.3
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ npm --version
3.10.10
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ code --version
1.15.1
41abd21afdf7424c89319ee7cb0445cc6f376959
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$
```

Granted, the instructions do say I need `git 2.9.x` or higher and I only have `git 2.7.4` but I am not sure that would cause a problem or the specific problem I'm seeing.  When I try to install composer-cli, I get:

```
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$ npm install -g composer-cli
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
/usr/lib
+-- composer-cli@0.11.3
  +-- chalk@1.1.3
.
.
.
    +-- yargs-parser@7.0.0
      +-- camelcase@4.1.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-91-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ibmadmin/hyperledger-composer/npm-debug.log
ibmadmin@pfuntner1:~/hyperledger-composer$
```

I removed much of the `npm install` output because I didn't think it was relevant and it was quite long.

As per the instructions, I am not running as root and am not surprised I don't have the access the install wants to a path like `/usr/lib/node_modules`.  I was running from an empty directory and the only thing that was created as `npm-debug.log`.  What should I do?

Comment: Although you are not running a root, you have installed node as root (maybe by doing sudo apt-get install node ?), so it is installed into directories where only root has write access to so you cannot install npm modules globally unless you are root or reconfigure npm to account for this.
You basically need to ensure you install node under your normal id and I would recommend using nvm to do this as it makes the whole process easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So fundamentally this is an npm issue. But strange to see it with your npm version above.

The normal route is one of these shown here
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Ideally, when you install composer modules globally (eg. composer-cli) you should install using a designated, non-root user - as you indeed tried to do. If there are issues (eg, on Ubuntu with permissions to write/update node directories located in system directories like /usr/local) - one solution (but see link earlier) is perform the npm install to a directory you have access to - rather than resort to root or superuser access, as this is not good practice. Here is what to do to set the npm prefix to a given directory, ...

"npm config set prefix /home/myuser/"

In this case, global binaries are placed in /home/myuser/bin which is in your PATH, and the modules are placed in /home/myuser/lib ...

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  That gets me past the problem but it's maybe just another reason why Node.js isn't my most favorite language in the world. :)